# Removing myself from a SharePoint & access notifications

Tags: user, notifications

I started a SharePoint @1 year ago as part of a project.  I've moved to a new role however I can't seem to stop the access notifications.  I have removed myself as the owner and no longer show up even in the users list.  How do I adjust the notifications recipient as well?

Answer (score 3):

The access request notifications are set at the root site in `Site Permissions`.  In the `Permissions` tab you will see `Access Request Settings`.  There you can set if you want to allow request and what email they are sent to.

[image]

[image]